# errors during implementation

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I doing a ROM and the code is fully synthesized and worked fine but shown to critical warning and when I run the implementation it shows" [Place 30-494] the design is empty" I have looked on xillinx website but no solution for this error. I will show my code here hope you guys help me:

```html
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module ROM(output [7:0] LED, [4:0] Ao, input [7:0] D, [4:0] A, Clear, Load);
reg [7:0] Store [0:31];

initial
    begin                       

    Store[0]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[1]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[2]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[3]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[4]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[5]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[6]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[7]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[8]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[9]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[10]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[11]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[12]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[13]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[14]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[15]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[16]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[17]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[18]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[19]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[20]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[21]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[22]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[23]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[24]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[25]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[26]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[27]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[28]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[29]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[30]<=4'b00000000;
    Store[31]<=4'b00000000;
    end
always @(*)
begin
  if(Load)
    if (D[7:0])
    begin
      Store[0]<= LED;
      Store[1]<= LED;
      Store[2]<= LED;
      Store[3]<= LED;
      Store[4]<= LED;
      Store[5]<= LED;
      Store[6]<= LED;
      Store[7]<= LED;
      Store[8]<= LED;
      Store[9]<= LED;
      Store[10]<= LED;
      Store[11]<= LED;
      Store[12]<= LED;
      Store[13]<= LED;
      Store[14]<= LED;
      Store[15]<= LED;
      Store[16]<= LED;
      Store[17]<= LED;
      Store[18]<= LED;
      Store[19]<= LED;
      Store[20]<= LED;
      Store[21]<= LED;
      Store[22]<= LED;
      Store[23]<= LED;
      Store[24]<= LED;
      Store[25]<= LED;
      Store[26]<= LED;
      Store[27]<= LED;
      Store[28]<= LED;
      Store[29]<= LED;
      Store[30]<= LED;
      Store[31]<= LED;
    end
    
  else if(A[4:0]) 
    begin
    Store[0]<= Ao;
    Store[1]<= Ao;
    Store[2]<= Ao;
    Store[3]<= Ao;
    Store[4]<= Ao;
    Store[5]<= Ao;
    Store[6]<= Ao;
    Store[7]<= Ao;
    Store[8]<= Ao;
    Store[9]<= Ao;
    Store[10]<= Ao;
    Store[11]<= Ao;
    Store[12]<= Ao;
    Store[13]<= Ao;
    Store[14]<= Ao;
    Store[15]<= Ao;
    Store[16]<= Ao;
    Store[17]<= Ao;
    Store[18]<= Ao;
    Store[19]<= Ao;
    Store[20]<= Ao;
    Store[21]<= Ao;
    Store[22]<= Ao;
    Store[23]<= Ao;
    Store[24]<= Ao;
    Store[25]<= Ao;
    Store[26]<= Ao;
    Store[27]<= Ao;
    Store[28]<= Ao;
    Store[29]<= Ao;
    Store[30]<= Ao;
    Store[31]<= Ao;
    end
    
  else if (Clear)
   begin
     Store[0]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[1]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[2]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[3]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[4]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[5]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[6]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[7]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[8]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[9]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[10]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[11]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[12]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[13]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[14]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[15]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[16]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[17]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[18]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[19]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[20]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[21]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[22]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[23]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[24]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[25]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[26]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[27]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[28]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[29]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[30]<=4'b00000000;
     Store[31]<=4'b00000000;
   end
end   
endmodule
```

the critical warning is

[Common 17-69] Command failed : Site can not be assigned to more then one port

Comment: Have you tried switching your assignments in the `initial` block to blocking assignments (`=`) rather than non-blocking (`<=`)? In this case, blocking is better as it is the first time initialization (everywhere else correctly uses non-blocking assignments for your sequential elements, ie the RAM).

Comment: yes I did it will not synthesis I dont know why it does that but thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your output (LED and Ao) are used as input in your code :

```
...
Store[15]<= LED;
...
Store[7]<= Ao;
...
```

it should be :

```
...
LED <= Store[15];
...
Ao <= Store[7];
...
```

If your outputs are never driven, the tool will simply not use neither the module nor the signal.

Comment: oh yah you are right. I just changed the whole thing and kept it as Store[A] <= D; for the Load and <=8'b00000000 for Clear and it worked

Answer (score 0):

After I did some changes on the assignment before the always block I changed the whole always block:

here is what I did and thank to @grorel :

```html
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module ROM(output [7:0] LED, [4:0] Ao, input [7:0] D, [4:0] A, input Clear, input Load);
reg [7:0] Store [0:31];
assign Ao = A;
assign LED = Store[A];
initial
    begin     

    Store[0]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[1]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[2]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[3]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[4]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[5]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[6]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[7]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[8]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[9]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[10]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[11]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[12]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[13]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[14]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[15]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[16]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[17]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[18]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[19]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[20]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[21]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[22]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[23]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[24]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[25]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[26]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[27]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[28]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[29]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[30]<=8'b00000000;
    Store[31]<=8'b00000000;
    end
always @(*)
begin
  if (Load) 
    begin
      Store[A]<= D;
    end
    
  else if (Clear)
   begin
     Store[A]<= 8'b00000000;
   end
   
end   
endmodule
```

also the initial should be 8 bit not 4bit